# Laravel: Query across relation-defined table

Tags: laravel

I have `$donor`, which is the `Donor` model.

Also, I have `Log` that is associated with `Donor` as defined by this relationship in the `Donor` model:

```
public function Log(){
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class,'DonorID','DonorID');
}
```

`$donor->load('Log');`, which eager load the `Donor` with all `Log` associated to it, would return this following

```
{
  "DonorID": "59060001",
  "DonorCitizenID": "1000000000009",
  "DonorPrefix": "Mx.",
  "DonorName": "John",
  "DonorSurname": "Smith",
  "created_at": "2016-06-21 08:06:44.000",
  "updated_at": "2016-06-23 02:15:10.000",
  "log": [
    {
    "LogID": 6,
    "DonorID": "59060001",
    "EventTypeID": "1",
    "EventDate": "2016-06-15",
    "EventBrief": "Donor Added",
    "created_at": "2016-06-15 06:01:06.000",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-15 06:01:06.000"
    },
    {
    "LogID": 21,
    "DonorID": "59060001",
    "EventTypeID": "2",
    "EventDate": "2016-06-23",
    "EventBrief": "Donor has rested in peace.",
    "created_at": "2016-06-23 02:30:49.000",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-23 02:30:49.000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I have this code of query that takes the inputted text from the field, finds the specific `donor`, and returns it.

```
  $donors = Donor::
    where('DonorCitizenID', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorCitizenID').'%')->
    where('DonorName', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorName').'%')->
    where('DonorSurname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorSurname').'%')->
    get();
```

It does as it says, get all the `Donor`s, only if it match the several criteria, and it worked well, as long as the data I matched is stored in the `Donor`.

But, I want another search field. This one would match the **latest** `Log` (as one `Donor` can has many `Log`s) in any donor by matching the `EventTypeID` in the loaded `Log`. How can I write the condition to do this?

Please kindly note that the returned value is expected to be the list of all `Donor`s matching the criteria.

Comment: Looking at your query, I think it should return you a `Collection` of **Donors** and not just a single `Donor`.

Comment: Yes, collection of donors.

Answer (score 1):

its should be done like this if i understood what you are saying

**edit**

```
$donors = Donor::
        where('DonorCitizenID', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorCitizenID').'%')
      ->where('DonorName', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorName').'%')
      ->where('DonorSurname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorSurname').'%')
      ->with(['Log' => function ($query) {  
         $query->where('EventType', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('EventType').'%')->get();
    }])->get();


$donor->Log // result
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, returning only the latest `Log` is not what I am seeking. I want to check the specific field in `Log` owned by `Donor`, and if it match that field, return the `Donor`, **in the same behavior my other queries match `DonorName`, `DonorSurname`, etc.** Something like `->where(Log->'EventType', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorSurname').'%')`

Comment: Oh, forget to edit the `Input`. In this case, it's `Input::get('EventType')`; for the `EventType` textbox.

Comment: just change the orderby to that `->where('EventType', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('EventType').'%')` also you can `->has` instead of `->with` and use the whereas mentioned above

Comment: check the edit , it will give you the donnor with the log

Comment: Thank you, however, does not work as expected. `Log` was eager loaded to `Donor` for only its first result, but not the others. Also, the added query still loads `Donor` which its latest `Log` didn't match `Input::get('EventType')`

Comment: ah easy fix , inside the closure(after the `->with`) change ->first to get (ill update the answer and i didnt understand what you mean in the second part , ah you want the donor that have the log =to input?

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas`[method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

```
$donors = Donor::
        where('DonorCitizenID', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorCitizenID').'%')
      ->where('DonorName', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorName').'%')
      ->where('DonorSurname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('DonorSurname').'%')
      ->whereHas('Log', function ($query) {  
            $query->where('EventType', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('EventType').'%');
        })->get();
```

Comment: This almost worked! However, I want to query only if `Donor`'s **latest** `Log`'s `EventType`. The following code stills returns `Donor`s that may have `EventType` as specified in the **previous** log, which is not needed.